# Tools for visualisation: making a video of a sliding windows moving on the time series

Tags: python, neural-network, visualization, jupyter, ipython

I have a Neural Network (an autoencoder) that gets as the input a time-window of length `M` from a time series of length `N`, (`M << N`), and transforms it to another same dimensional time-window.

In purpose of visualization, I want to make a video that shows input of the NN in the top of the frame and the corresponding output in the bottom of the frame, runnig the NN on consecutive windows.

I was wondering if you could introduce me some tools or give me some hints on this.

Answer (score 1):

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34486703/5210098), I've written a script for it.

```
%matplotlib notebook

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

plt.ion() 
size_x = 128
def pltts(ts1, ts2, ax, colors, lbl):
    x = np.linspace(0,2.5,size_x)
    if ax.lines:
        ax.lines[0].set_xdata(x)
        ax.lines[1].set_xdata(x)

        ax.lines[0].set_ydata(ts1)
        ax.lines[1].set_ydata(ts2)
    else:
        l1, l2 = ax.plot(x, ts1, colors[0], x, ts2, colors[1])
        fig.legend((l1, l2), ("BLUE", "RED"), loc='center', fontsize=fnt_siz-2)
        ax.set_title(lbl, fontsize=fnt_siz-2)
    fig.canvas.draw()

fnt_siz = 16

fig,ax = plt.subplots(2,1, figsize=(10,10))
fig.suptitle('Data', fontsize=fnt_siz)
ax[0].set_xlabel('Time', fontsize=fnt_siz-4)
ax[0].set_ylabel('Magnitude', fontsize=fnt_siz-4)
ax[1].set_xlabel('Time', fontsize=fnt_siz-4)
ax[1].set_ylabel('Magnitude', fontsize=fnt_siz-4)
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.75)
# ax[0].grid(True)
# ax[1].grid(True)
for f in range(50):
    ts1 = np.random.normal(0, 4, size=(size_x,1))
    ts2 = np.random.normal(1, 1, size=(size_x,1))
    pltts(ts1, ts2, ax[0], ['b', 'r'], "ORGINAL")
    ts1 = 2*ts1
    ts2 = -3*ts2
    pltts(ts1, ts2, ax[1], ['b', 'r'], "TRANSFORMED")
    time.sleep(1)
```

This is a sample output:

[image]